# Why is Kylo Ren separated from the other Knights Of Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, snoke

In the movie you just see a glimpse of the Knights Of Ren.

The question   [Where were the Knights of Ren during the events of The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/where-were-the-knights-of-ren-during-the-events-of-the-force-awakens) sort of answers where they are in The Force Awakens.

So why was he alone fighting for the First Order without the Knights Of Ren? Did Snoke order him to fight there?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our policy on "future works"

Comment: @Richard, Hey Richard, what is "Future Works"? Cheers

Comment: @KyloRen: the general idea is that we close questions which are asking about plots of movies, TV shows, books etc. (“works”) that aren’t released yet (i.e. they’re in the “future”), because, well, they can’t really be answered until the work *is* released. Here’s [the discussion on this policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based), although I’m not sure we have an actual policy written down anywhere.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite. Thanks for the info. Sometimes it is hard to know if the information is in this episode or is actually something that is a future plot. I guess that is where the community comes in.

Comment: Basically it applies to any questions left unanswered by an *ongoing* franchise; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: @KyloRen: yeah totally, and there are novelisations of movies that sometimes have further details. Having your question closed doesn’t mean you were wrong to ask it.

Comment: @KyloRen Not all of the Knights of Ren were force sensitive, so they could not be trained, so it seems logical that he would fight without the non-force sensitive members of KoR, as they would just slow him down (to an extent) - related question, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176957/did-the-students-who-fled-with-kylo-ren-become-the-knights-of-ren?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Duplicate of [Where were the Knights of Ren during the events of The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114636/where-were-the-knights-of-ren-during-the-events-of-the-force-awakens/258921#258921)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren), "the Knights' true loyalty was to Sidious". Interestingly, though, the article also states that they helped overthrow Sidious previously, indicating that they have a rogue streak. The first detail would indicate that Sidious had them working on other things when he did not need them with Kylo Ren. The second would suggest that they were more independent of the First Order (as they served multiple masters and fought on various sides over the years), so they did not always go with Kylo (similar to how the Inquisitors did not always stay with Vader, but were technically his personal Jedi-hunting team).